# Remove bestow target, does it become a creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-bestow

If my opponent was to cast bestow onto a creature, and i then remove the creature, does the bestow get countered and go to the graveyard, or does it become a creature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It becomes a creature, because the rules make a special exception for bestow. Even though you've cast your creature with bestow as an aura spell, when it resolves, it can end up as an aura *or* a creature. From the bestow section of [The Mechanics of Theros](https://web.archive.org/web/20160120034702/http://archive.wizards.com/magic/magazine/Article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/feature/therosmechanics):

> If the target creature leaves the battlefield after you cast a card with bestow as an Aura but before the spell resolves, the Aura spell will resolve as an enchantment creature rather than being countered like a normal Aura spell. If the target creature is still on the battlefield when the Aura spell resolves, it resolves as an Aura enchanting that creature.

And the specific rules for this case:

> 702.102a ... These effects [turning it into an Aura spell] last until one of two things happens: this spell has an illegal target as it
> resolves or the permanent this spell becomes, becomes unattached. ...

> 702.102d As an Aura spell with bestow begins resolving, if its target is illegal, the effect making it an Aura spell ends. It continues resolving as a creature spell and will be put onto the battlefield under the control of the spell’s controller. This is an exception to rule 608.3a.

(Rule 608.3a is the rule about how aura spells normally resolve, which would cause a normal aura spell to go to your graveyard at this point.

Comment: That's what I call a reminder rule. If you read the definition of Bestow (702.102a), you'll see it says it stops becoming an Aura enchantment if the target becomes illegal. At that point, you're left with an Enchantment Creature on the stack, while will resolve as any other Enchantment and/or Creature.

Comment: @ikegami Well, okay, 702.102a and 702.102d say the same thing, but 702.102d spells it out in more detail, so it still seems pretty useful here. (And tiny nit: it says "as it resolves", so I don't think you ever have an Enchantment Creature spell on the stack waiting to resolve.)

Comment: I wasn't disagreeing. I was just adding more info.

Answer (score -1):

Usually when an aura card is being cast targeting a creature, it would become countered and put in the graveyard when the creature isn't there anymore. However, bestow auras are an exception because they will just enter the battlefield as a creature in that case.

Comment: why the downvote? the answer is basically the same as Jefromi's only with less details

Answer (score -5):

Short answer is yes, the spell goes to the graveyard if there is no creature for it to bestow. This means you need an instant removal spell like doomblade, lightning strike etc... and must cast IN RESPONSE to the bestow being cast.

Comment: This is true of normal auras, but not bestow. There are special rules for bestow, letting it resolve as a creature if it no longer has a target to enchant. See for example [bestow in the mechanics of Theros summary](http://archive.wizards.com/magic/magazine/Article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/feature/therosmechanics#c).